# Find $r$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

Consider the distinct complex numbers $a, b, c$, all having the same modulus $r$. Determine $r$, knowing that the numbers $a - bc$, $b - ac$, and $c - ab$ are real.

We know that $\bar{a} = \frac{r^2}{a}$, and we know that $a - bc$ and the others are real numbers. So, we can write $a - bc = \bar{a} - \bar{b}\bar{c}$, and then by adding the relations, we get that $(abc - r^4)(a + b + c) - (abc - r^2)(ab + bc + ca)=0$. I got stuck here. How can I continue?

Answer (score 2):

$a-bc, b-ac, c-ab \in \mathbb R \implies x^2(abc+r^4)-(r^2+abc)(abc) =0\text{ has infinite solutions}$which means that for any $|x| = r$, $x-\frac{abc}x$ will always be $\in \mathbb R$. This is possible only if $r^4=-abc$ and $r^2=-abc$. This means $r^4-r^2=0$, giving only one possible value for $r=1$. Then $a,b,c$ can be written in polar form, $e^{ix}, e^{iy}, e^{iz}$ respectively. That means we can write $e^{i\pi} = e^{i(x+y+z)}$, or that $x+y+z=\pi$.

So, the solution can only occur if $x+y+z=\pi\land r=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is built upon RandomGuy's answer, but yields a different result, one that shows the *existence* of solutions, indeed contradicting their answer. It agrees with Sahaj's result.

Using RandomGuy's equation on line 2, $r\sin\alpha=r^2\sin(\beta+\gamma)$, we have
$$\sin(\alpha)=r\sin(\beta+\gamma)=r\sin(D-\alpha)=r\sin(D)\cos(\alpha)-r\cos(D)\sin(\alpha)\\
\implies r\sin(D)\cdot\cos(\alpha)+(-1-r\cos(D))\cdot\sin(\alpha)=0.$$
This means $x=r\sin(D),\ y=(-1-r\cos(D))$ is a solution to the equation $x\cos(\alpha)+y\sin(\alpha)=0.$ This equation represents a straight line passing through the origin with normal vector $(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))$, and the point $p=(r\sin(D), -1-r\cos(D))$ is on that line. Similarly, $p$ is on the lines $x\cos(\beta)+y\sin(\beta)=0$ and $x\cos(\gamma)+y\sin(\gamma)=0$. Since, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct, at most two of the three lines can fully overlap. So, those three lines have a unique intersection at the origin, and $p=(0,0)$.

Therefore, we must have
$r\sin(D)=0$ and $-1-r\cos(D)=0$. Since $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct, we have $r>0$.
$$r\sin(D)=0,\ r > 0 \implies \sin(D)=0 \implies \cos(D)=\pm1;\\
-1-r\cos(D)=0 \implies r\cos(D)=-1 \implies r=1,\ \cos(D)=-1.$$
In other words, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=D\equiv\pi\pmod{2\pi}$ and $r=1$, agreeing with Sahaj's result.

We've shown $D\equiv\pi$ and $r=1$ is a necessary condition. It is also sufficient, since every implication here can be reversed. For an example, take
$$a=-i,\ b=i,\ c=-1;\\
a-bc=0,\ b-ac=0,\ c-ab=-2.$$